# Как задать относительный путь в Asp.Net Core к папке .git

Tags: c#, git, asp.net-core, path

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как прописать относительный путь в web приложении (Asp.net core) к папке, в которой находится **.git**? Например если создать консольное приложение, то относительный путь получается прописать так:

```
(@"../../../../../")
```

Это получается путь идет относительно **.exe**, который находится например в `C:\Project\App\App.UI\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1`, где **.git** находится в папке Project, а если так же пройтись из веб-приложения, то ошибка пути. Относительно чего же надо идти? И как правильно прописать относительный путь к папке **.git** (веб-приложение находится в `C:\Project\App\App.Web`)

P.S. Работаю с библиотекой LibGit2Sharp, там нужно путь к репозиторию прописать, .git уже лежит там. Писать абсолютный путь не вариант, потому что нужно, чтоб у остальных разработчиков находило по этому пути.

Comment: зачем вам это делать? По идее, когда вы запускаете своб программу на проде, там не должно быть никаких папок git

Comment: Работаю с библиотекой LibGit2Sharp, там нужно путь к репозиторию прописать, .git уже лежит там. Писать абсолютный путь не вариант, потому  что нужно, чтоб у остальных разработчиков находилось по этому пути

Comment: [IWebHostEnvironment.WebRootPath Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.iwebhostenvironment.webrootpath?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostEnvironment_WebRootPath)

Answer (score 0):

Оказывается плясать надо от папки с веб-приложением, получается в моем случае относительный путь будет таковым: (@"../../").

Comment: @Sevastopol' если это решает проблему, то это и должно быть в ответе, а не в вопросе. Возможно этот ответ стоило бы дополнить, но это явно ответ, а не дополнение к вопросу.